# Advice on db architecture with Fauna

Tags: faunadb

I'm building a todo list with a few interrelated collections (tasks, groups, and columns to store the ids and orders of the tasks). Each one of these need to be scoped down to the logged in user, so I've got indexes to fetch _by_owner (owner is the term).

I want to make sure it's not going to create a bottleneck if the application scales to 1000s of users. If so, is there a better pattern to implement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using index terms to filter collection sets is *the* way to go in fauna. Terms partition collections into a family of disjoint sets such that all docs in each subset have equal terms. This is done at write time so subsequent reads by term are cheap.